# Rally 2 SDK: combo box filter for each column in a grid

Tags: rally

I have a rallygrid and I want to create a combobox/text search box for each column in the grid. The combobox will be populated with possible values for the column. Selecting a value in the combobox will filter the grid accordingly.

Is there a built-in way in Rally to do this? Or do I have create everything manually and tie it up together?

This is my rallygrid:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    store: customStore,
    columnCfgs: [
        { text: 'Project', dataIndex: 'Project' },
        { text: 'Type', dataIndex: 'Type' },
        { text: 'State', dataIndex: 'State' }
    ]
});
```

I want to create 3 comboboxes which can search and filter the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by the grid included in the 2.0 preview SDK but it's probably on our backlog somewhere to implement this since pages like Backlog in Rally have it.

You may be able to use some user contributed examples to get you started:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150918-Grid-Header-Filters&p=660276#post660276
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: Yes, even I got the idea from the Rally Backlog. I ended up using the FiltersFeature to kind of do it. Thanks for your suggestions!